# Interactive bash script

Tags: shell-script, output

I'm writing a script that shuts down the Apache service, performs a function, and turns it back on.

I'd like to get some type of interactive confirmation for each process. I'm not familiar with printf, but I believe it would be required for what I want to do.

Here's a portion of the script below. As I turn off the service, I would like it to say what it will do, then report OK or NOT OK on the same line.

ie.

`Shutting down Apache service:`

few seconds later...

`Shutting down Apache service: OK`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Turn off Apache
echo "Shutting down Apache service:'

service apache2 stop

if ( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep apache2 | wc -l) > 0 )
then
echo "NOT OK!"
else
echo "OK!"
fi
```

Comment: Just test the exit status of the service command: `if (( $? != 0 )); then printf "%s\n" "Not OK"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can use the `-n` option of `echo` not to print the end of line.

```
echo -n Shutting down Apache service:
```

or, use `printf`

```
printf '%s' 'Shutting down Apache service'
```

To include the newline in `printf`, put `\n` into the template

```
printf '%s\n' 'NOT OK!'
```